# Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found 2022 iOS

Tags: ios, flutter

```
failed to emit precompiled header 
'/Users/ilimigroup/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-
gnlvgjtjekrdyiawrmkviasejldi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders
/Runner-Bridging-Header-swift_RVTAE63V2JGN-clang_23R92LSS7CH78.pch' for 
bridging header '/Users/ilimigroup/StudioProjects/telia-
ios/telia/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h
```

Getting this error. Can't figure out the solution.

Comment: Please use code tag to highlighted all errors

Answer (score 0):

Just remove below folders in IOS

1. .symlinks
2. pods
3. podfile.lock

after it did do flutter clean and flutter pub get and run the app.

Comment: the same issue come

Comment: have you tried to remove the IOS folder and recreate it?

Comment: it's okay. i solve using a flutter docs https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/ios/project-setup